# Why is there a bug (auto-attribution?) in my draw method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to define a "draw" method which selects people for a Secret Santa.

The goal is to pass an array of names, and a hash of couples so that:
- everyone has a "target" to which he will offer his gift.
- the method cannot attribute the partner of the person(defined by couples) *if* this person is in couples(as key or value).
- and of course, the method cannot attribute a person to himself.

I made this method, which works 90% of the time, and I can't figure out how to fix it without testing it at the end and relaunch the method if it fails.
The way it fails is that, sometimes, the last person doesn't get someone attributed.

```
class Array
   def except(value)
     self - [value].flatten
   end
 end

def draw(names, couples)

  associations = Hash.new

  names.each { |participant| associations[participant] = 0 }

  associations.each do |key, value|
    (couples.has_key?(key.to_sym) || couples.has_value?(key.to_sym)) ? (target = names.except([key, couples[key.to_sym]]).sample) : (target = names.except(key).sample)
    associations[key] = target
    names.delete(target)
  end

  # print the results
  associations.each do |key, value|
    puts "\t#{key}\t offre à  #{value} \n "
    # sleep(0.3)
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a sample `names` and `couples` where it fails?

Comment: @muistooshort Hello, yes here are the samples I use :  names = %w(PA Aude Jean Cécile Pauline Clement Marion Marius Laura Jéremie Maxime Olivier Laurie Marine Raph Flo Alice Steph Mathy Cloé Nano Eline Paul) and couples_hash = {
  "PA": "Pauline",
  "Aude": "Jean",
  "Cécile": "Flo",
  "Marius": "Alice",
  "Laura": "Steph",
  "Olivier": "Laurie",
  "Marine": "Raph",
  "Mathy": "Cloé",
  "Nano": "Eline"
}

Comment: Don't put your response to a question asking for data into a comment. Instead, edit your question and add that information into it as if the data had been there originally. Don't add "edited:" or "updated" tags as we can tell what changed. Using a comment forces potential answerers to read every comment and try to piece together the question and related data, which wastes everyone's time.

Comment: Try your best to get the grammar correct and we'll fix any mistakes. Also, don't apologize for inexperience. Instead, make sure you ask good questions and you'll do fine. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages and you'll have the important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest a more Ruby-like way of doing that, letting someone else identify the problem in your code.

Suppose the couples are as follows.

```
couples = [["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Bob", "Phoebe"], ["Oona", "Mac"],
           ["Ava", "Billy-Bob"]]
```

(`couples.flatten.names` gives us an array of names, should we need that.)

**Helper method**

First let's create a method to select a person that is not a partner for the first member of each couple. For the present do not worry about randomisation.

```
def allocate_first_members(couples)
  (couples.each_cons(2).map { |c1,c2| [c1.first, c2.first] } << 
    [couples.last.first, couples.first.first]).to_h
end
```

Let's try it.

```
allocate_first_members(couples)
  #=> {"Lucy"=>"Bob", "Bob"=>"Oona", "Oona"=>"Ava", "Ava"=>"Lucy"}
```

I've chosen to return a hash because it seems more useful when it's time to assign each person a giftee.

Let's step through the calculations.

```
enum = couples.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Bob", "Phoebe"], ["Oona", "Mac"], 
  #                  ["Ava", "Billy-Bob"]]:each_cons(2)>
```

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). We can see the three values that will be generated by this enumerator and sent to the block by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Bob", "Phoebe"]],
  #    [["Bob", "Phoebe"], ["Oona", "Mac"]],
  #    [["Oona", "Mac"], ["Ava", "Billy-Bob"]]]
```

Continuing,

```
a = enum.map { |c1,c2| [c1.first, c2.first] }
  #=> [["Lucy", "Bob"], ["Bob", "Oona"], ["Oona", "Ava"]] 
b = a << [couples.last.first, couples.first.first]
  #=> [["Lucy", "Bob"], ["Bob", "Oona"], ["Oona", "Ava"], ["Ava", "Lucy"]] 
b.to_h
  #=> {"Lucy"=>"Bob", "Bob"=>"Oona", "Oona"=>"Ava", "Ava"=>"Lucy"}
```

So "Lucy" is to gift "Bob", "Bob" is to gift "Oona" and so on.

See [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h). In computing `a` the first element is generated by `enum`, sent to the block and the block variables are assigned values using a process called [Array Decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
c1,c2 = enum.next
  #=> [["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Bob", "Phoebe"]] 
c1
  #=> ["Lucy", "Lilly"] 
c2
  #=> ["Bob", "Phoebe"]
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). The block calculation can now be performed.

```
[c1.first, c2.first]
  #=> [c1.first, c2.first]
  #=> ["Lucy", "Bob"]
```

The remaining steps in computing `a` are similar. The start of the next one is:

```
c1,c2 = enum.next
  #=> [["Bob", "Phoebe"], ["Oona", "Mac"]]
```

This method obviously ensures that no person's giftee is their partner.

**Main method**

We can now write the main method.

```
def draw(couples)
  shuffled = couples.shuffle.map(&:shuffle)
  h = allocate_first_members(shuffled)
  shuffled = shuffled.map(&:reverse).shuffle
  h.merge(allocate_first_members(shuffled))
end
```

and see what we get.

```
draw(couples)
    #=> {"Billy-Bob"=>"Lilly", "Lilly"=>"Mac", "Mac"=>"Phoebe",
    #    "Phoebe"=>"Billy-Bob", "Lucy"=>"Ava", "Ava"=>"Bob",
    #    "Bob"=>"Oona", "Oona"=>"Lucy"}
```

Let's go through the calculations. To ensure that the first member of each couple is randomly assigned a giftee, we can first shuffle the couples:

```
  shuffled = couples.shuffle
    #=> [["Ava", "Billy-Bob"], ["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Oona", "Mac"],
    #    ["Bob", "Phoebe"]]
```

See [Array#shuffle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle). We can then shuffle the order of the two persons that make up each couple:

```
  shuffled = shuffled.map(&:shuffle)
    #=> [["Billy-Bob", "Ava"], ["Lilly", "Lucy"], ["Mac", "Oona"],
    #    ["Phoebe", "Bob"]]
```

`shuffled.map(&:shuffle)` is more-or-less shorthand for:

```
shuffled.map { |couple| couple.shuffle }
```

Now we use the helper method to assign the giftee for each of the first members of each couple.

```
  g = allocate_first_members(shuffled)
    #=> {"Billy-Bob"=>"Lilly", "Lilly"=>"Mac", "Mac"=>"Phoebe",
    #    "Phoebe"=>"Billy-Bob"}
```

We now want to assign giftees to the second member of each couple in `shuffled`. To use the help method we need only reverse the order of each couple:

```
  shuffled = shuffled.map(&:reverse)
    #=> [["Ava", "Billy-Bob"], ["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Oona", "Mac"],
    #    ["Bob", "Phoebe"]]
```

We should reshuffle the couples once more.

```
  shuffled = shuffled.shuffle
    #=> [["Lucy", "Lilly"], ["Ava", "Billy-Bob"], ["Bob", "Phoebe"],
    #    ["Oona", "Mac"]]
```

We can now use the helper method once more:

```
  h = allocate_first_members(shuffled)
    #=> {"Lucy"=>"Ava", "Ava"=>"Bob", "Bob"=>"Oona", "Oona"=>"Lucy"}
```

Lastly, we need to merge `g` and `h`:

```
  g.merge(h)
    #=> {"Billy-Bob"=>"Lilly", "Lilly"=>"Mac", "Mac"=>"Phoebe",
    #    "Phoebe"=>"Billy-Bob", "Lucy"=>"Ava", "Ava"=>"Bob",
    #    "Bob"=>"Oona", "Oona"=>"Lucy"}
```

I could have instead used [Array#shuffle!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle-21) and/or [Array#map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21)

Comment: Thank you very much it is indeed better to proceed like this!